# Web scraping data with line breaks

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data off this url: https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/browse/home/specialdeals/mac/macbook_pro/13

I am trying to retrieve the line that says

8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory

or

16GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory

in each container in `containers = soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'product'})` using BeautifulSoup. The problem is it has line breaks and multiple newlines around it, which makes it difficult for me to parse. How can I retrieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the best bet here is combine `BeautifulSoup` with `regular expressions`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/browse/home/specialdeals/mac/macbook_pro/13"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for td in soup.select('td.specs'):
    m = re.search('^(8|16).*?onboard memory.*?$', td.text, flags=re.M|re.I)
    if not m:
        continue
    print(td.select_one('h3').text.strip())
    print('Full text: {} | Memory: {}'.format(m[0].strip(), m[1]))
    print('-' * 80)
```

This code finds all products with 8 or 16 GB and prints them:

```
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina display - Space Grey
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina display - Silver
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 2.0GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina Display — Space Grey
Full text: 8GB of 1866MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina display - Silver
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina display - Space Grey
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch Macbook Pro 2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina Display - Space Grey
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch Macbook Pro 2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina Display - Silver
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch Macbook Pro 2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina Display - Silver
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 3.1GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina display - Silver
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch MacBook Pro 3.1GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with Retina display - Space Grey
Full text: 8GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refurbished 13.3-inch Macbook Pro 3.3GHz Dual-core Intel Core i7 with Retina Display - Space Grey
Full text: 16GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory | Memory: 16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: ***[Check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755623/failed-to-grab-dates-in-a-cutomized-manner-out-of-a-tabular-content)*** @Andrej Kesely. I suppose you can solve this. Thanks.