# Failed to grab dates in a cutomized manner out of a tabular content

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse some dates available within a table in a webpage. The table is located under the header `NPL Victoria Betting Odds`. The tabular data are within the id `tournamentTable`. You can see the three dates there `10 Aug 2018`,`11 Aug 2018` and `12 Aug 2018`. I wish to parse and arrange them according to my expected output below.

***[Webpage link](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/australia/npl-victoria/)***

This is my attempt so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "find the link above"

def get_content(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tournamentTable tr"))):
        try:
            idate = items.find_element_by_css_selector("th span[class^='datet']").text
        except Exception: idate = ""
        try:
            itime = items.find_element_by_css_selector("td.table-time").text
        except Exception: itime = ""

        print(f'{idate}--{itime}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_content(driver,link)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Currently I'm having output like:

```
--
10 Aug 2018--
--
--09:30
--10:15
11 Aug 2018--
--
--05:00
--05:00
--09:00
12 Aug 2018--
--
--06:00
--06:00
```

My expected output:

```
10 Aug 2018--09:30
10 Aug 2018--10:15
11 Aug 2018--05:00
11 Aug 2018--05:00
11 Aug 2018--09:00
12 Aug 2018--06:00
12 Aug 2018--06:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
def get_content(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    dates = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tournamentTable tr.center.nob-border"))))
    for d in range(dates):
        item = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#tournamentTable tr.center.nob-border")[d]
        try:
            idate = item.find_element_by_css_selector("th span[class^='datet']").text
        except Exception: idate = ""
        for time_td in item.find_elements_by_xpath(".//following::td[contains(@class, 'table-time') and not((preceding::tr[@class='center nob-border'])[%d])]" % (d + 2)):
            try:
                itime = time_td.text
            except Exception: itime = ""
            print(f'{idate}--{itime}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Selenium, but selected dates can be extracted with just BeautifulSoup. The timedates are coded as Unix timestamp inside tag classes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import datetime

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
r = requests.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/australia/npl-victoria/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for td in soup.select('table#tournamentTable td.datet'):
    for c in td['class']:
        if re.match(r't\d+', c):
            unix_timestamp = int(re.match(r't(\d+)', c)[1])
            d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_timestamp).strftime('%d %b %Y--%H:%M')
            print(d)
```

Prints:

```
10 Aug 2018--09:30
10 Aug 2018--10:15
11 Aug 2018--05:00
11 Aug 2018--05:00
11 Aug 2018--09:00
12 Aug 2018--06:00
12 Aug 2018--06:00
```

If you want also the matches printed:

```
for td in soup.select('table#tournamentTable td.datet'):
    for c in td['class']:
        if re.match(r't\d+', c):
            unix_timestamp = int(re.match(r't(\d+)', c)[1])
            d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_timestamp).strftime('%d %b %Y--%H:%M')
            print(d, end=' ')
            print(td.find_next('td').text)
```

Prints:

```
10 Aug 2018--09:30 Melbourne Knights - Port Melbourne Sharks
10 Aug 2018--10:15 Pascoe Vale - Dandenong Thunder
11 Aug 2018--05:00 Avondale FC - Bentleigh Greens
11 Aug 2018--05:00 Northcote City - Bulleen
11 Aug 2018--09:00 Hume City - Oakleigh Cannons
12 Aug 2018--06:00 Heidelberg Utd - Green Gully
12 Aug 2018--06:00 South Melbourne - Kingston City
```

Comment: It's utterly difficult to select the best one between the two of your's. However, I'm stick to the solution provided by sir Andersson as he used the same approach I tried above using selenium. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You the issue is that the items is either an idate or an itime. so you are overwriting one of them every time.

I commented out your `excepts`, and it prints fine for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/australia/npl-victoria/"

def get_content(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    idate = ''
    itime = ''
    for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tournamentTable tr"))):
        try:
            idate = items.find_element_by_css_selector("th span[class^='datet']").text
        #except Exception: idate = ""
        except:
            pass
        try:
            itime = items.find_element_by_css_selector("td.table-time").text
           # print('itime: ',itime)
       # except Exception: itime = ""
        except:
            pass
        if idate !='' and itime !='':
            print(f'{idate}--{itime}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_content(driver,link)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried your approach but the problem is it produces extra rows. The expected output should be exactly 7 rows as I've shown above but your solution gives me 13 or something. Thanks for your solution, though.